# How can I update a label's text when a row in the datagridview is changed?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

On my form I have a label (lblBalance) and I have a DGV which is populated from an Access database. If I add, delete or update a row, how can I refresh the label text so it reflects the new balance?

This is my frmMain code so far:

```
    Public Class frmMain

      Private Sub TransactionsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TransactionsBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TransactionsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.CheckingDataSet)

      End Sub

      Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CheckingDataSet.Transactions' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.TransactionsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CheckingDataSet.Transactions)
        lblTotalCredits.Text = BalanceTotal().ToString("c")
      End Sub

      Private Function BalanceTotal() As Double
        Dim tot As Double = 0
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For i = 0 To TransactionsDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
            tot = tot + Convert.ToDouble(TransactionsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
        Next i
        Return tot
      End Function
    End Class
```

Comment: If you are dealing with money, you should probably consider using the Decimal type instead of the Double type.

Comment: use DGV events like `DGV.RowsRemoved`

Answer (score 0):

The BindingSource control has a `ListChanged` event you can try using to update your balance label.

```
Private Sub TransactionsBindingSource_ListChanged(_
                sender As Object, _
                e As ListChangedEventArgs) _
                Handles TransactionsBindingSource.ListChanged

  lblTotalCredits.Text = BalanceTotal().ToString("c")

End Sub
```

Comment: I added this code, but now it throws an InvalidCastException on this line in the BalanceTotal() function.

tot = tot + Convert.ToDouble(TransactionsDataGridView.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)

Any ideas?

Comment: @user1618156 What is the value in the cell?  Try using [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of `Convert.ToDouble`.  Since you have a datasource, you shouldn't have to get these values from the grid, I would get them straight from the datasource.